# How do you format a float to the first significant decimal and with specified precision

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust (and coming from a Javascript background), so I decided to build a number formatting application to learn more about it.

One function in the application can accept a tiny float (e.g. `0.000435`), and a precision value (e.g. `2`), and should return the float formatted to the first significant decimal and with the specified precision applied (e.g. `0.00044`)

For example, the function should accept and return the following:

```
  fn meh(float: f64, precision: usize) -> String {
    // ... magic happens ... format!(...
  }

  let float = 0.000456;
  let precision = 2:
  let result_a = meh(float, precision);
  // result_a => "0.00046"

  let float = 0.043256;
  let precision = 3:
  let result_b = meh(float, precision);
  // result_b => "0.0433"
```

I know that `format!` helps with precision. But I can't find a decent way to find the first significant decimal with out doing something funny like "convert float to a `String` and iterate until a non-zero value is found...."

I hope that makes sense, any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Would exponential notation as the output suffice? Otherwise, your use of "precision" and the standard meaning will differ.

Comment: There would be no exponential notation. The float wont/shouldn't be small enough to need it. Also, I'm aiming to format the float for display to an end user who may not expect/understand exponential notation.

Comment: Floats support precision formatting, but Rust's concept of precision is "how many digits after the decimal point should be printed". i.e. `println!("{:.4}", 1.3333333333);` gives `1.3333`

Comment: Agreed, which I mentioned in the question regarding my understanding of `format!` and how it can help in my situation. The main body of this question is that I'm looking for a solution that can find the first significant decimal place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Rust's interpretation of "precision" is "number of digits after the decimal point". However, if we instead want it to mean "number of significant digits", we can write the `meh` function to take this into account:

```rust
fn meh(float: f64, precision: usize) -> String {
    // compute absolute value
    let a = float.abs();

    // if abs value is greater than 1, then precision becomes less than "standard"
    let precision = if a >= 1. {
        // reduce by number of digits, minimum 0
        let n = (1. + a.log10().floor()) as usize;
        if n <= precision {
            precision - n
        } else {
            0
        }
    // if precision is less than 1 (but non-zero), then precision becomes greater than "standard"
    } else if a > 0. {
        // increase number of digits
        let n = -(1. + a.log10().floor()) as usize;
        precision + n
    // special case for 0
    } else {
        0
    };

    // format with the given computed precision
    format!("{0:.1$}", float, precision)
}
```

[Playground example with test cases](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ad723c4cdc074bba08ece0be0ff0c55)

Comment: Thank you. Looks like the missing piece was my understanding was logarithms and `log10`

Comment: I think log10 is quite a slow way to do this. You can probably do it quicker just by looking at the actual digits.

Comment: Also this code doesn't work unless the significant figures extend past the decimal point. E.g. consider this testcase: `(1456.789, 2, "1500"),`.